# TypeError: node.getIterator is not a function when using VuePress

Tags: vuepress

I'm following https://v1.vuepress.vuejs.org/guide/getting-started.html#quick-start to generate a new VuePress site.
I did the following (I'm using Node 15.4.0):

```sh
npx create-vuepress-site
cd docs
npm install
npm run build
```

I'm getting:

> TypeError: node.getIterator is not a function
> at LazyResult.visitTick (/home/marcin/tmp/vuepress-testing/docs/node_modules/optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin/node_modules/postcss/lib/lazy-result.js:528:33)
> at LazyResult.runAsync (/home/marcin/tmp/vuepress-testing/docs/node_modules/optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin/node_modules/postcss/lib/lazy-result.js:408:30)
> at LazyResult.async (/home/marcin/tmp/vuepress-testing/docs/node_modules/optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin/node_modules/postcss/lib/lazy-result.js:221:30)
> at LazyResult.then (/home/marcin/tmp/vuepress-testing/docs/node_modules/optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin/node_modules/postcss/lib/lazy-result.js:206:17)
> at OptimizeCssAssetsWebpackPlugin.processCss (/home/marcin/tmp/vuepress-testing/docs/node_modules/optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin/src/index.js:81:8)
> at Object.processor (/home/marcin/tmp/vuepress-testing/docs/node_modules/optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin/src/index.js:20:18)
> at /home/marcin/tmp/vuepress-testing/docs/node_modules/last-call-webpack-plugin/src/index.js:150:10
> at arrayEach (/home/marcin/tmp/vuepress-testing/docs/node_modules/lodash/_arrayEach.js:15:9)
> at forEach (/home/marcin/tmp/vuepress-testing/docs/node_modules/lodash/forEach.js:38:10)
> at OptimizeCssAssetsWebpackPlugin.process (/home/marcin/tmp/vuepress-testing/docs/node_modules/last-call-webpack-plugin/src/index.js:147:5)
> at /home/marcin/tmp/vuepress-testing/docs/node_modules/last-call-webpack-plugin/src/index.js:178:28
> at AsyncSeriesHook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (/home/marcin/tmp/vuepress-testing/docs/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), :25:17)
> at AsyncSeriesHook.lazyCompileHook (/home/marcin/tmp/vuepress-testing/docs/node_modules/tapable/lib/Hook.js:154:20)
> at /home/marcin/tmp/vuepress-testing/docs/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:1409:36
> at AsyncSeriesHook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (/home/marcin/tmp/vuepress-testing/docs/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), :9:1)
> at AsyncSeriesHook.lazyCompileHook (/home/marcin/tmp/vuepress-testing/docs/node_modules/tapable/lib/Hook.js:154:20)

I also noticed that the same error started to appear on my existing VuePress site, which worked without issues before (I think even yesterday).
What is the problem? Am I able to get around it somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same here.
I locked vuepress to version 1.8.1, and build seems fine... until bug fix.

Comment: How did you do that? I tried setting `"vuepress": "^1.8.1"`, but after `npm install` and `npm run build` I get the same error.

Comment: Nevermind, got it (`"vuepress": "1.8.1"`)